# Removing marker shadows in Gmaps4Rails with CoffeeScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, gmaps4rails

I am using the custom marker option in gmap4rails and implementing mainly in CoffeeScript. Though the default option for markers is to add a shadow, I wish to remove it but could not locate anywhere the setting to remove a shadow from a marker.

The view:

[image]

The Class to create the custom markers:

```
class CustomMarkerBuilder extends Gmaps.Google.Builders.Marker
    create_marker: ->
      options = _.extend @marker_options(), @rich_marker_options()
      @serviceObject = new RichMarker options

    rich_marker_options: ->
      marker = document.createElement("div")
      marker.setAttribute('class', 'custom_marker_content')
      marker.innerHTML = this.args.custom_marker
      marker.shadow
      { content: marker }
```

The CoffeeScript action to show all markers:

```
allLocations = root.table.rows().data()
  $('#multi_markers').map ->
    handler = Gmaps.build("Google", builders: { Marker: CustomMarkerBuilder })
    handler.buildMap
      internal:
        id: "multi_markers"
    , ->
      for aLocation in allLocations
        markers = handler.addMarkers([
          {
            lat: aLocation[9]
            lng: aLocation[10]
            custom_marker:     "<img src='/assets/images/redDotMarker.png' width='40' height='40'>"
            custom_infowindow: "Store Number: #{aLocation[1]}; Address: #{aLocation[2]}, #{aLocation[3]}; Major Bidding City: #{aLocation[6]}"
          }
        ])
      handler.bounds.extendWith markers
      handler.fitMapToBounds()
      return
```

**How can the shadow be removed from the markers in the CoffeeScript?**

Answer (score 2):

Append `@serviceObject.setShadow("")` to remove marker shadows.

```
class CustomMarkerBuilder extends Gmaps.Google.Builders.Marker
  create_marker: ->
    options = _.extend @marker_options(), @rich_marker_options()
    @serviceObject = new RichMarker options
    @serviceObject.setShadow("") # Added
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the options of RichMarker. To do that change the return value in your function `rich_marker_options`.

This is done by changing
`{ content: marker}` -> `{ content: marker, flat: true }`

Your final code for `rich_marker_options` would look like this

```
rich_marker_options: ->
  marker = document.createElement 'div'
  marker.setAttribute 'class', 'custom_marker_content'
  marker.innerHTML = this.args.custom_marker
  marker.shadow
  {content: marker, flat: true}
```

I found out by looking how RichMarker is constructed on this [page](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-rich-marker/examples/richmarker.html)